Do we need actually to integrate?
Here is the question I was reading its solution here Ergodic T invariant measures that can not be Lebesgue measures.:
Let $T: S^1 \to S^1$ be the rotation of the circle by $90$ degrees. I want to find an ergodic $T$-invariant measure.
Here is the solution given there:
Call $\mu_x$ the measure in question. Then for $\phi:X\to\mathbb{R}$ a function one has
\begin{align*}
\int \phi\circ f(y) d\mu_x(y)
= \dfrac{\phi\circ f(x)+\phi\circ f(f(x))+\cdots+\phi\circ f(f^{p-2}(x))+\phi\circ f(f^{p-1}(x))}{p}
= \dfrac{\phi\circ f(x)+\phi\circ f^2(x)+\cdots+\phi\circ f^{p-1}(x)+\phi\circ f^{p}(x)}{p}
= \dfrac{\phi\circ f(x)+\phi\circ f^2(x)+\cdots+\phi\circ f^{p-1}(x)+\phi(x)}{p}
=\int\phi d\mu_x(y),
\end{align*}
so that $\mu_x$ is $f$-invariant.
My questions are:
Can we just do it without integration, since $\mu$ is $f$-invariant iff $$\mu(f^{-1}(U)) = \mu(U)$$ for all $U$?
Also, from where the last equality in the integration above came?where has the $f$'s gone?
Could anyone clarify these points to me please?

There is no need for integrals:
Take a set $U$ and let $n_1,\dots,n_k$ be the integers in $\{0,\dots,p-1\}$ such that
$$
f^{n_i}(x)\in U\quad\text{for $i=1,\dots,k$}.
$$
Then $\mu(U)=k/p$. Now note that
$$
f^n(x)\in f^{-1}U\quad\text{if and only if}\quad f^{n+1}(x)\in U.
$$
Therefore, letting $m_1,\dots,m_l$ be the integers in $\{1,\dots,p\}$ such that
$$
f^{m_i}(x)\in U\quad\text{for $i=1,\dots,l$},
$$
we have $l=k$ and $m_i=n_i+1$ for $i=1,\dots,k$. This gives
$$
\mu(f^{-1}U)=\frac lp=\frac kp=\mu(U).
$$
As for the last equality with the integral, recall that $f^p(x)=x$ and so
\begin{align*}
&\dfrac{(\phi\circ f)(x)+\cdots+(\phi\circ f^{p-1})(x)+(\phi\circ f^{p})(x)}{p}\\
&= \dfrac{(\phi\circ f)(x)+\cdots+(\phi\circ f^{p-1})(x)+\phi(x)}{p}\\
&= \dfrac{\phi(x)+(\phi\circ f)(x)+\cdots+(\phi\circ f^{p-1})(x)}{p}.
\end{align*}
